# How to get the information using JQ

Tags: json, parsing, key, jq

I have a url http://vis-vip.xxx.xx.net:8080/xx/info which returns the below result
{"application.name":"var-integration-xx","application.version":"1.13.0-241","os.name":"Linux"}.

I need to get the application version from the above result.
I have JQ installed. Is there a way to get the version info usng JQ?

Comment: Duplicate of [How to use jq when the variable has a period](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37018393/how-to-use-jq-when-the-variable-has-a-period)

Answer (score 1):

```
jq -r '."application.version"'
```

1.13.0-241

Comment: Good.  Take a read of the manual, it's very informative - https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.5/ Meanwhile how about accepting the answer.  Thx