# jq parse json with key which has special character DOT (.)

Tags: json, grep, jq

I have a json

```
{ "fundingMoved": {
    "com.mytest.map": {
        "map": {
            "java.util.HashMap": {
                "AGREEMENT_OWNING_ORG": "ABC 22",
                "WAREHOUSE": "XYZ 6"
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to write a script to see if `AGREEMENT_OWNING_ORG` contains `ABC` and `WAREHOUSE` contains `XYZ`

My script so far

```
grep . jk_raw | jq -r ".fundingMoved."com.mytest.map""
```

This is returning null but

```
grep . jk_raw | jq -r ".fundingMoved
```

This returns result .

Issue . Due to the Dot (.) in key it is not returning the response

I checked this related post [How to use jq when the variable has reserved characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37018393/how-to-use-jq-when-the-variable-has-reserved-characters)

This is suggesting to use double quote. I tried that but still response is null.

I tried to escape character . as . that doesnt help either

How to extract value from this

Comment: You need to use single quotes for the outermost level and double quotes inside `'.fundingMoved."com.mytest.map"'` or escape the inner double quotes `".fundingMoved.\"com.mytest.map\""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to write a script to see if AGREEMENT_OWNING_ORG contains ABC and WAREHOUSE contains XYZ

Please, please, don't use `grep` for such tasks.  Rather, consider something along these lines:

```
< jk_raw jq '.. | objects | select(has("java.util.HashMap"))."java.util.HashMap"
   | (.AGREEMENT_OWNING_ORG | test("ABC")) and (.WAREHOUSE | test("XYZ"))'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion . I am using legacy code and it is accepting only grep as param.I try to use your jq related suggestions