# Parsing a JSON values using jq with key containing a '-' character

Tags: json, jq

I have a json file that looks like this:

```
{
    "list": {
        "foo": {
            "host": "www.someurl1.com"
        },
        "bar": {
            "host": "www.someurl2.com"
        },
        "baz": {
            "host": "www.someurl3.com"
        },
        "foo-beta": {
            "host": "www.someurl4.com"
        }
    },
    "currentServer": "foo-beta"
}
```

When the value of `"currentServer"` is `"foo"` or `"bar"` or `"baz"`, I can read it using the following (for foo):

```
jq .list.foo.host test.json
```

However, when value of `"currentServer"` is `"foo-beta"`, meaning anything that has a `'-'` character I get an error. I have tried the following:

```
jq .list["foo-beta"].host test.json
```

Or

```
jq .list.foo-beta.host test.json
```

Or

```
jq .list | .["foo-beta"].host test.json
```

I'm an Embedded Software engineer who usually works with low-level programming in C, haven't used `jq` much before and the constraint is using `jq` for this as the target platform has this requirement.

Additionally, is there a way I can come up with a `jq` command usage which will allow me to read the `"currentServer"' and pass it as follows, or similar:

```
CURR_SERVER=jq currentServer test.json
CURR_SERVER_URL=jq .list.$CURR_SERVER.host test.json
```

`jq` version I am using is v1.6.

Comment: as for your second question, ```CURR_SERVER=$(jq .currentServer test.json)``` - but as a rule of thumb, you should avoid asking multiple questions in the same thread on SO.

Comment: `jq -r '.list[.currentServer].host' test.json` will get you there in one go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jq '.list."foo-beta".host'
```

- but i'm voting to close this question as a duplicate of [How to use jq when the variable has reserved characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37018393/how-to-use-jq-when-the-variable-has-reserved-characters)

Comment: Yes, that helped. Thanks. However, `CURR_SERVER_URL=jq '.list.$CURR_SERVER.host' test.json` doesn't work. Any thoughts?

Comment: @WedaPashi try $()  and double-quotes instead of single-quotes eg ```CURR_SERVER_URL=$(jq ".list.$CURR_SERVER.host" test.json)```  - but that should be its own dedicated question, avoid asking multiple questions in a single thread on this website.

Comment: Don't inject code. If you want to pass on values, use the `--arg` option instead. Also, you may want to use the `--raw-output` (or `-r`) option to decode the JSON string for output.