# JQ filter for a single JSON file

Tags: json, jq

I have a file containing

```
{
  "solr.jetty": {
    "org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DefaultHandler.requests": {
      "count": 432742,
      "meanRate": 0.1393530774422645,
      "1minRate": 0.1582358234691172,
      "5minRate": 0.24472281886082692,
      "15minRate": 0.32856666658514566,
      "min_ms": 0,
      "max_ms": 124,
      "mean_ms": 19.05039312538189,
      "median_ms": 1,
      "stddev_ms": 27.68447649619781,
      "p75_ms": 61,
      "p95_ms": 63,
      "p99_ms": 64,
      "p999_ms": 67
    }
  }
}
```

I want `jq` command to print the "count" field.

I read many web pages with a lot of dumb examples and I didn't get yet my filter to use because I find it all very counterintuitive.

P.D: do you know any **good** jq tutorial or guide?

Comment: Edit your question to show the cmd that you really expected to work. Then readers can help explain why it didn't work. Good luck.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use jq when the variable has reserved characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37018393/how-to-use-jq-when-the-variable-has-reserved-characters)

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is an actual question or a rant. At the same time, it is asking for recommendations, which is clearly off-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jq '."solr.jetty"."org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DefaultHandler.requests".count'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to minimize typing, consider:

```
..|.count? // empty
```